# Permission error when creating Flutter project

Tags: ubuntu, flutter, dart, permissions

I am new to Flutter, and after installing it, I got this error when I tried to create a project.

```
[hello_world] flutter create --ios-language swift --android-language kotlin .
Failed to open or create the artifact cache lockfile: "FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/home/raphael/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)"
Please ensure you have permissions to create or open /home/raphael/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile
Failed to open or create the lockfile
exit code 1
```

I can't find any way to fix this, so I'd be glad if someone helps me :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check permission for the mentioned directory via:

```
ls -l /home/raphael/flutter/
```

the flutter subfolder in there should have the same user id (or the group) as your current user, with whom you are trying to create the project.

If not, while being in the folder mentioned above, try to change permission on the folder via:

```
chown -R YOUR_USERNAME flutter
```

Run the first command again to verify that the apropriate user is now shown on the folder. Then try to create the project again.

Comment: If `flutter` is in your current user's home directory, you can run the following command instead: `chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/flutter`

Comment: in my case, I need to add sudo

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R [user]:root /opt/flutter
```

It worked for me on Manjaro Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, worked in my ubuntu 18.04.

First set the ownership of the folder:

```sh
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/development/flutter
```

If you still have the error set this permission:

```sh
sudo chmod 754 development/flutter/
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this error, I opened the terminal with administrator privileges and It worked!
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo chown -R <username> /Users/<username>/.config
```

or this one work for me

```
$ sudo chmod 775 <username> /Users/<username>/.config
```

For full right

```
$ sudo chmod 777 <username> /Users/<username>/.config
```

Please, make sure to replace `<username>` by your account username.